# Consider $A = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ . what is the boundary of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider  $A  = \mathbb{R}  \times \{0\}  \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ . what  is  the  boundary of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

My thinking : $A  = \mathbb{R}  \times \{0\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ then boundary of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Finally my answer is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is not  subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is closed and it has no interior. So its boundary is $A$ itself. You cannot say that the boundary is $\mathbb R$ even though it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: To the proposer: $B=(-1,1)\times \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R.$ E.g.  for $r\in \Bbb R$ let $f(r)=(r/(1+|r|),\,0).$ Then $f:\Bbb R\to B$ is a homeomorphism. But in $\Bbb R^2$ the boundary of $B$ is $B\cup \{(-1,0),(1,0)\}=[-1,1]\times \{0\}.$